# Declaring a variable twice in two extensions of the same struct in Swift?

Tags: swift, struct, extension-methods

I'm currently working through the Swift tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/getting-started-with-scrumdinger) and do not fully understand the concept below, where the `data` variable is seemingly declared twice, once in each extension of the struct `DailyScrum`.

What is the purpose of declaring the `data` variable in the second extension, given we later call the `Data` struct with `@State private var data: DailyScrum.Data = DailyScrum.Data();`?

```
extension DailyScrum {
    static var data: [DailyScrum] {
        [
            DailyScrum(title: "Design", attendees: ["Cathy", "Daisy", "Simon", "Jonathan"], lengthInMinutes: 10, color: Color("Design")),
            DailyScrum(title: "App Dev", attendees: ["Katie", "Gray", "Euna", "Luis", "Darla"], lengthInMinutes: 5, color: Color("App Dev")),
            DailyScrum(title: "Web Dev", attendees: ["Chella", "Chris", "Christina", "Eden", "Karla", "Lindsey", "Aga", "Chad", "Jenn", "Sarah"], lengthInMinutes: 1, color: Color("Web Dev")),
        ]
    }
}


extension DailyScrum {
    struct Data {
        var title: String = "";
        var attendees: [String] = [];
        var lengthInMinutes: Double = 30.0;
        var color: Color = .random;
    }

    var data: Data {
        return Data(title: title, attendees: attendees, lengthInMinutes: Double(lengthInMinutes), color: color)
    }

}
```

Comment: The first declaration is `static var`, the second one is non-static. Two completely different entities, it's OK to have the same name.

Comment: It might be ok but it’s a bad habit to use the same name like this in one type, it might lead to confusion and mistakes. It’s also questionable to name a type the same as a built in type even if it is defined internally inside another type.

Comment: In the next step of the tutorial (after `@State private var data: DailyScrum.Data = DailyScrum.Data();`), there is the line `data = scrum.data`. That's where you use the second `data`.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson 100% agree with you. I just pointed out to the possible source of confusion :).

Comment: Ok makes sense, a static variable is a different entity to non-static and therefore can share the same names, but not a great idea. Thanks!